# Difference between ({}) and Object.prototype

Tags: javascript

This works

```
if (typeof Object.prototype.clone === "undefined"){
     Object.prototype.clone = function() {}
}`
```

But why is clone undefined here ?

```
if (typeof ({}).clone === "undefined"){
           ({}).clone = function() {}
    }`
```

`

Comment: They are both `undefined`. Also, your syntax is incorrect. It shouldn't be `({}).clone`, it should be: `{}.clone`

Comment: @ScottMarcus `{}.clone` is a syntax error, at least in V8. `({}).clone` is correct.

Comment: thank you'all. I appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Your second code snippet does "work", but it doesn't do anything useful.

```
({}).clone = function() {}
```

creates a property of that single empty object created with `({})`. You give that object a "clone" property, but because you don't save the object anywhere the net effect is that nothing permanent happens.

`Object.prototype`, on the other hand, is a way to make lasting changes to the runtime that affect all objects. There are numerous online and published resources for studying how the JavaScript prototypal inheritance system works. [Here is a good place to start, for example](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) in addition to many questions right here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: And, of course, modifying native prototypes is generally a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, though the evil of the practice varies by situation. For a web application without 3rd party scripts, for example, and when done carefully with `Object.defineProperty()`, it's just an implementation choice.